# How to set different colors for each part of the compound in Cannon.js?

Tags: colors, cannon.js

I'm trying to make a compound with several boxes in different colors using addShape() method.
But apparently It seems like you can only set one color for one rigid body.
Is there any ways to set different colors for each boxes out of a compound?

Comment: What renderer are you using? Are you using the demo renderer, which is provided with cannon.js (CANNON.Demo)?

Comment: Yeah. I'm using the demo renderer. Can I set multiple colors on one body which is made out of several other shapes?

Comment: Okay.. then how did you set the color of one rigid body? All rigid bodies share the same THREE.Material?